# Problems reading a .zip file in R

Tags: r, unzip

I am trying to unzip a .zip of Formula 1 data from this [website](https://ergast.com/mrd/db/) using the following code:

```
dat <- unzip(zipfile = "http://ergast.com/downloads/f1db_csv.zip")
```

However, each time I do so I get the following error message:

```
error 1 in extracting from zip file
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think that unzip will only work with local files,  not URLs. You can make this work by downloading first.

```
download.file("http://ergast.com/downloads/f1db_csv.zip", "f1db_csv.zip")
unzip("f1db_csv.zip")
```